# Why is Buna-S called so?

Tags: polymers, rubber, etymology

Styrene Butadiene synthetic rubber is also called Buna-S. It is the abbreviation of Butadiene (Bu) Sodium (Na) Styrene (S). 
Why is Sodium included?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sodium is included in the name because it was essential in the chain polymerization that forms the rubber.
Sodium served as the initiator for the anionic polymerization.